# Does WCF scale well using WebOrb?

Tags: c#, apache-flex, wcf, scalability, weborb

I'm looking for feedbacks regarding performances using WCF with amf.

Here's an old benchmark which doesn't use WCF :
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/developer-den/technical-articles/amf-vs-webservices.html

I'm aiming to few hundred/thousand concurrent connections at the same time.
I think there's an overhead using WCF, but I would like to know to what extent if anyone has already test WCF through WebOrb using AMF behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience I can tell you that your bottleneck is going to be IIS.  WPF won't really act any differently than any other client-side technology that uses amf3.  Everything is going to depend upon your server resources.

1) Google "IIS Concurrent Requests".

2) Refine your global.asax so that it isn't a slow-me-down sand-pit.

Best of luck,
Jeremy

Comment: Not WPF, I'm talking about WCF (Unified web services)

Comment: Yo.  Yeah, IIS is still going to be your hurdle.  We have six server instances sitting behind a load balancer. Those instances (sitting on a $1Mil server we purchased a couple of years ago) act as pretty high-end machines... things start slowing down when one IIS instance hits 100 concurrent connections with each one cranking out a complex request.  Your difficulties will be different that ours, but finding exact metrics for your server's capabilities will be difficult.  That said, if your server-side methods are light, you probably won't hit too many limits.  Things should be screamin' fast!

Answer (score 0):

If IIS is the performance hurdle as Jeremy suggests, is there an opportunity for you to run your application as a self-hosted service? Here is a document that will show you how in case you can run it that way.

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/index.html?standalone_wcf_services.htm

Comment: I guess my question is more, how much does WCF weight on performances (overhead etc..) in comparison with simple invokation